# How to plot 2 kinds of chart on the same chart use EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel-2007, epplus

I want to draw 2 different type series (i.e. Column & Line) on one chart in EPPlus (a COM helping export Excel file). Anybody know how to do that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally, I've found my answer.
Link ref: http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ

**How can I add a series with a different chart type to my chart?**

Here's how you do...

```
ExcelChart chart = worksheet.Drawings.AddChart("chtLine", eChartType.LineMarkers);        
var serie1= chart.Series.Add(Worksheet.Cells["B1:B4"],Worksheet.Cells["A1:A4"]);
//Now for the second chart type we use the chart.PlotArea.ChartTypes collection...
var chartType2 = chart.PlotArea.ChartTypes.Add(eChartType.ColumnClustered);
var serie2 = chartType2.Series.Add(Worksheet.Cells["C1:C4"],Worksheet.Cells["A1:A4"]);
```

Comment: Do you have an idea how i can apply datalabel.showvalue=true for the series2 only ?? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this...

```
var chartType2 = chart.PlotArea.ChartTypes.Add(eChartType.ColumnClustered)as ExcelBarChart;
(ExcelBarChartSerie) serie2 = (ExcelBarChartSerie) chartType2.Series.Add(Worksheet.Cells["C1:C4"],Worksheet.Cells["A1:A4"]);
serie2.DataLabel.ShowValue = true;
```